QGIS - getting the graphics from the OSM standard to polygon representing my research area
I´m new to QGIS and are trying to make a copy of a certain area:

But I want the graphics and scale to follow along from the original map. Not just retrieve a single color polygon.
The polygon is I have is a temporary scratch layer using a polygon as shape.
I tried Raster->Extract from projection-> Then using the Layer OSM Standard and the option Draw on Canvas, but then I get Error 4.
How can I get a part of the map as an own layer, with intact graphics that I can zoom in on?

Hello, could you  expand a bit more on your expected result ? What do you want to achieve with the OSM raster subset ? I understand you would like a zoomable OSM raster (with increasing detail as you zoom?), only in a specific bounding polygon ? If so you can revert your polygon layer to mask the OSM raster outside the polygon

@Kasper That's what I want - How can I do that?

Edit your polygon layer Style, and select Inverted polygon instead of Single Symbol. The colour fill will be everywhere outside the polygon

Exactly what I wanted. Thank you so much! (:
